# How to open an .xlsb file in R?

Tags: r, xlsb

I'm trying to open an .xlsb file in R and keep getting similar errors.

Any recommendations on how to solve this issue without having to download the data and save it in a different formate?

```
read.xlsx(paste(OutputLocation,FileName, sep=""), sheetName = "Master Data")
```

**Error messages:**
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.apache.poi.xssf.XLSBUnsupportedException: .XLSB Binary Workbooks are not supported

```
rigDataWB<-loadWorkbook(paste(OutputLocation,FileName, sep=""))
```

**Error messages:**
Error: XLSBUnsupportedException (Java): .XLSB Binary Workbooks are not supported

**Please note:**

I cannot install Perl libraries.

I'm running 64bit R.

**Reference:**
http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=779

**My data is from:** 
http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=79687&p=irol-reportsother

Answer (score 16):

Use the `RODBC` package:

```
library(RODBC)
wb <- "D:\\Data\\Masked Data.xlsb" # Give the file name
con2 <- odbcConnectExcel2007(wb)
data <- sqlFetch(con2, "Sheet1$") # Provide name of sheet
nrow(data)
```

Answer (score 6):

One way could be to use ODBC:

```
require(RODBC)
if (any(grepl("*.xlsb", odbcDataSources(), fixed = TRUE))) {
  download.file(url = "http://phx.corporate-ir.net/External.File?item=UGFyZW50SUQ9NTcwMjI1fENoaWxkSUQ9MjcxMjIxfFR5cGU9MQ==&t=1", 
                destfile = file.path(tempdir(), "test.xlsb"), 
                mode = "wb")
  conn <- odbcConnectExcel2007( file.path(tempdir(), "test.xlsb")) 
  df <- sqlFetch(conn, sub("'(.*)\\$'", "\\1", sqlTables(conn)$TABLE_NAME)[4]) # read 4th sheet in the table name list
  head(df, 10)
  #                                             F1          F2         F3       F4        F5 F6
  # 1                                         <NA>        <NA>       <NA>     <NA>      <NA> NA
  # 2                                         <NA>        <NA>       <NA>     <NA>      <NA> NA
  # 3                                         <NA>        <NA>       <NA>     <NA>      <NA> NA
  # 4                                         <NA>        <NA>       <NA>     <NA>      <NA> NA
  # 5  Baker Hughes Gulf of Mexico Oil / Gas Split        <NA>       <NA>     <NA>      <NA> NA
  # 6                                         <NA>        <NA>       <NA>     <NA>      <NA> NA
  # 7                                         <NA> US Offshore Total\nGoM Gas\nGoM Oil \nGoM NA
  # 8                                       1/7/00         127        123      116         7 NA
  # 9                                      1/14/00         125        121      116         5 NA
  # 10                                     1/21/00         125        121      116         5 NA
  close(conn) 
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note, if you're getting an error, update your Windows drivers [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255) and the solution works.

Comment: Hi. Is this answer obsolete now? There doesn't seem to be a `odbcConnectExcel2007` in `RODBC`. Or is this Windows only?

Comment: I'm using windows and `odbcConnectExcel2007 ` does exist.

Answer (score 3):

[`readxlsb`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxlsb/index.html) package can read Excel binary (.xlsb) files into R. Here are some info taken from the package vignettes:

> `read_xlsb(path, sheet, range, col_names, col_types, na, trim_ws, skip, ...)`
>
> **sheet:**
>
> Either a name, or the index of the sheet to read. Index of the first sheet is 1. If the sheet name is embedded in the range argument, or implied if range is a named range, then this argument is ignored
>
> **range:**
>
> range can be specified as
>
> - A named range. Named ranges are not case sensitive
> - In Sheet!A1 notation
> - In Sheet!R1C1 notation
> - As a cellranger::cell_limits object
>
> **col_names**
>
> - TRUE: The first row is used for column names. Empty cells result in a column name of the form ‘column.i’
> - FALSE: Column names will be ‘column.i’
> - Character vector: vector containing column names.
>
> **col_types**
>
> Can be implied from the spreadsheet or specified in advanced. When specifying types, options are
>
> - “logical” (or “boolean”), “numeric” (or “double”), “integer”, “date” and “string” (or “character”)
> - Use “skip” (or “ignore”) to skip a column
>
> **na**
>
> A character string that is interpret as NA. This does not effect the implied data type for a column.
>
> **trim_ws**
>
> Should leading and trailing whitespaces be trimmed from character strings?
>
> **skip**
>
> The number of rows to skip before reading data.

```r
library(readxlsb)

res = read_xlsb(path = system.file("extdata", "TestBook.xlsb", package = "readxlsb"), 
                range = "PORTFOLIO", 
                debug = TRUE)

ls(res$env)
#> [1] "content"      "named_ranges" "sheets"       "stream"

res$env$named_ranges
#>             name                     range sheet_idx first_column first_row
#> 1   INFO_RELEASE          FirstSheet!$A$11         0            1        11
#> 2        OUTLOOK 'My SecondTab'!$A$1:$C$13         1            1         1
#> 3      PORTFOLIO      FirstSheet!$A$3:$C$9         0            1         3
#> 4 SAVED_DATETIME          FirstSheet!$C$13         0            3        13
#> 5          TITLE           FirstSheet!$A$1         0            1         1
#>   last_column last_row
#> 1           1       11
#> 2           3       13
#> 3           3        9
#> 4           3       13
#> 5           1        1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This package is eye-wateringly slow for XLSB files of any meaningful size, and often does not complete successfully. Not that there is a real packaged alternative, but users should be mindful of this when they write code that depends on `readxlsb`.

Comment: This package doesn't work and freezes the R Studio.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on linux. Very slow for 100k records but got there.

Comment: This package has very limited features, for instance I cant skip NA or Blank cells while reading.

Comment: @Duffer: you can try Python packages ([pyxlsb](https://github.com/willtrnr/pyxlsb) or [pyxlsb2](https://github.com/DissectMalware/pyxlsb2) via [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)) to work around some of the limitations of the `readxlsb` package. I haven't tested them though.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the following error in R trying to connect to `.xlsb`:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

then, you are probably are missing to install the `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe` from Microsoft. I had this problem today, and after installing this file I've got no more error messages.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
xl.read.file(file_path, h=T, top.left.cell = "A1") from library(excel.link)
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation on how your code works?